# How to ensure a DataGridView entirely invisible before I show other MDI forms in the same area?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, components, mdichild

so I have a winform app to show some data.I have a DataGridView in the form,and I need to make it invisible after I click a button,and then begin show some MDI forms in the datagridview area.

```
dataGridView.Visible = false;
showAllMDIForms();
```

but all the mdi forms will pop out befor the DataGridView become invisible.
So how can I ensure the datagridview is entairly invisible??

Comment: You could insert a dataGridView.Refresh();

Comment: @TaW Thanks for comment.But I have tried it before,and it's not working...

Comment: It should imo. It needs to be right after setting Visible=false

Comment: Not sure in what context you're using that code, but try to BeginInvoke() that method (e.g., `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> showAllMDIForms()));`)

Comment: @Jimi Yeah... I have tried something like `new Task(showAllMDIForms).Start();`,it turned out that no mdi form was shown...

Comment: That's not even close that what I suggested.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry about that. But I tried your code ,still all the mdi forms pop out before the datagridview become invisible.

Comment: That seems quite improbable. Anyway, since you, apparently, are calling that code in a Button.Click event, make the event handler `async` and insert `await Task.Delay(100);` between the two calls.